# MYSQLI + PHP | Вывод информации из бд

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте, как с помощью mysqli+php вывести из таблицы "users" в столбце "hwid" строчку в которой "login"(еще один столбец) будет равен NickName(допустим тут ник) ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо при авторизации проверять строку hwid, именно введённого логина, а не полностью столбец hwid.
Буду благодарен за помощь.
Кусок неработающего кода:

```
$data = $_POST;
  if(isset($data['do_login']) ) 
  {
    $errors[] = array();
    $user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
    $hwid = $connect->query("SELECT hwid FROM users WHERE login = $data['login']");

    if ($user) {
        if ($hwid == array($data['hwid'])) {
                    if (password_verify($data['password'], $user->password)) {
            echo "Авторизирован!";
        }
        else {
            echo 'Не верный пароль!';
        }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Не верный hwid!';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Пользователь с таким логином не найдет!';
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result= $connect->query("SELECT hwid FROM users WHERE login = $data['login']");
$finfo = $result->fetch_field();
$hwid = $finfo->hwid
```

В переменной `$hwid` будет находится строка из столбца `hwid`. Можете сравнивать ее с чем захотите.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то так:

```
SELECT hwid FROM USERS WHERE LOGIN LIKE 'NickName';
```

Должно вывести hwid из той строки, в которой login = 'NickName'.

Comment: Вот допустим получили мы строку hwid где логин L9mur, как проверить данную переменную допустим на "тут должен быть hwid пользователя"?
Спасибо.

Comment: Держите, должно заработать. Второй запрос Вам делать было незачем, $user хранит в себе поле hwid. 
https://pastebin.com/sZqdf6pD

Comment: Оно то работает, но если я войду под логином и паролем другого пользователя у которой другой hwid, все ровно залогиниться!
Потому что он тупо полностью дампит столбец hwid, и ищет сравнение с введенным hwid.
А надо чтобы он дампил строку hwid только под введенным логином, а не полностью весь столбец

Comment: Никак нет. R::findOne вернёт **одну** строку, в которой логин будет равен тому, что был послан в POST-е, поэтому и hwid там будет всего один. Никаких дампов столбцов там быть не может просто по определению. Если вы, конечно, не изменяли код, который я скинул.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
SELECT hwid FROM users WHERE login = 'NickName'
```

Comment: Вот допустим получили мы строку hwid где логин L9mur, как проверить данную переменную допустим на "тут должен быть hwid пользователя"? Спасибо

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ae42q4j8
Вот кусочек кода. (он не работает)